# Exporting SHP to DXF without attributes

Tags: qgis, export, dxf

I have exported a polygon shapefile in QGIS 3.16 as a DXF by selecting 'Feature symbology' as the Symbology export options.
When I open it in Global Mapper and use 'Feature Info Tool' to select a polygon, I see the image below:

[image]

By visualizing the Feature Information, I see the attributes as below:

[image]

As shown in this image, under 'Attributes', there are two elements present: DXF-HATCH-START-LINE and ELEVATION. This file will be applied further for procedures that require it to not having any attributes and the Feature Information Attribute column has to be empty.
I am not familiar with CAD at all -- is it possible to this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you describe your .DXF export process in QGIS (i.e. are you exporting a single layer using the [Export][Save Features As] dialog, or are you exporting the entire project using the [Project][Import/Export][Export Project to DXF] dialog)?
2. If **single layer export**:
   Have you tried setting the geometry type to polygon (as opposed to automatic)?
3. If **entire project export**:
   Have you tried checking the [Force 2d output] checkbox?
4. In QGIS, where do your source layers come from? Have you confirmed that the layers do not already contain the corresponding attribute info prior to exporting the DXF? If so, you might be able to delete the specific fields prior to export. "$ELEVATION" is one of the DXF Header Variables in the official file specification. I have never run across "DXF_HATCH_START_LINE".
5. I guess it is possible that "DXF_HATCH_START_LINE" is a derived property based on the specific symbology. In that case, you could try setting the symbology to a solid color prior to export and see if the attribute is still created (assuming it didn't exist upon original import into QGIS).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @GSC_Mapper. I exported as a single layer: Export > Save features as. I tried setting the geometry type to polygon as point 2 you mentioned but I still see the two fields.

Comment: For point 4, the attribute table of my shapefile has only one field and that is DN. If I delete that, all layer will be deleted

Comment: As for point 5, the symbology is already a solid color. It is not a hash.

Comment: This shapefile is created from a raster file using polygonize tool